# Write xls in old (2003) format

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to write a file in excel 2003 format (xls) and not xlsx. Any package suggestions? `write.xlsx` don't do it I guess?

Comment: [WriteXLS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/index.html) will write to an Excel 2003 XLS file.

Comment: If it's a one-off, you can always open it in Excel and save it as .xls manually...

Comment: its part of a pipeline. must be automated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can save you data to xlsx. After, you can convert the xlsx file to xls with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_XLSX_File <- "D://excel_File_XLSX.xlsx"
path_To_XLS_File <- "D://excel_File_XLS.xlsx"

xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_XLSX_File)

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat
xlWbk$SaveAs(path_To_XLS_File, 56)
```